# How can I add a second Minikube cluster to Argo CD?

Tags: minikube, argocd

I have created 2 Minikube clusters (dev and prod) with purpose to add them as a solution with Argo CD. I can't add second cluster (dev) on Argo CD.

What I did...

### Cluster dev

minikube start -p dev

### Cluster prod

minikube start -p prod
minikube profile prod

### Install Argo CD in cluster prod

kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml

### Expose service

kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8081:443

### Argo CD login

argocd login localhost --username admin

### I have tried to add dev cluster on Argo CD (Argo CD is installed on prod cluster) and got the error below

```
$ argocd cluster add dev --name dev
WARNING: This will create a service account `argocd-manager` on the cluster referenced by context `dev` with full cluster level privileges. Do you want to continue [y/N]? y
INFO[0001] ServiceAccount "argocd-manager" already exists in namespace "kube-system" 
INFO[0001] ClusterRole "argocd-manager-role" updated    
INFO[0001] ClusterRoleBinding "argocd-manager-role-binding" updated 
FATA[0001] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get "https://127.0.0.1:55640/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:55640: connect: connection refused
```

### kube/config file

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.27.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://127.0.0.1:55640
  name: dev
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.27.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://127.0.0.1:55409
  name: prod
```

### Anyone knows how to add second Minikube cluster on Argo CD?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working via the `--core` flag

```
argocd cluster add minikube-0 --core
```

*Edit: this works to add the cluster, but the argocd pods cannot reference a localhost IP for an external cluster.  This blog post has further detail: https://ihaveabackup.net/2022/02/15/getting-argocd-working-in-kind/